# noise at idle after replacing new clutch

Tags: clutch, noise

Some noise is coming when the car is running at idle.  The noise goes away when the clutch pedal pressed.  This is happening immediately after replacing the clutch and clutch release bearing. what will be the root cause of this noise?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the car, Make, Model, Year. Who replaced the clutch, you or garage. Is the clutch cable, mechanical or hydraulic. Is the bearing partial run or constant run?

Comment: Would you describe the noise as "chatter?" (Think slightly muted snare drum.)

Comment: Did the pilot bearing get changed? Was the transmission checked for issues, primarily the front bearing?

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good chance that the clutch throwout bearing was not inserted flush into the 'throwout arm'.

If the bearing is off center (which is possible but not guaranteed) it can make some strange whirring noises.